# Right function within string (Excel 2007 VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, save-as

Okay: I'm working on a macro in Excel '07 that will import a file, deliniate the data, make the necessary formatting changes, and then save the file with a specified filename to a network drive, all with one click.

Everything works but that last part. I'm trying to save the file as paystatusMMDD.xlsx, where MMDD are the last 4 characters in a cell (L2). But I can't, for the life of me, get the Right function to work correctly. So what am I doing wrong? I'm sure it's obvious, but I can't figure it out.

Here's the relevant section of code:

```
Dim Path As String
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FileName2 As String
Path = "G:\HRO\PSM\PAYSTATUS\"
FileName1 = "paystatus"
FileName2 = Right(L2, 4)
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName1 & FileName2 & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlNormal
End Sub
```

Comment: use `Right(Range("L2"), 4)` or `Right(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L2"), 4)` to specify also sheet name which cell `L2` belongs to

Comment: @simoco Can you submit an answer so the question can be marked as answered?  I've noticed that you like to answer questions with comments instead of answers... out of curiosity, how come?

Comment: @PortlandRunner, not actually I like it, but in that case it's more a *comment* than answer:) Feel free to post it as answer if you'd like:)

Comment: @simoco no problem, I just don't want to take credit for your work but have and OCD thing going about open post :-)

Comment: @PortlandRunner - so as not to look like you are claiming credit, you can mark the answer "community wiki".

Answer (score 2):

Per @simoco comment, you need to correct the way you're referencing cell `L2`.

Use `Range("L2")` in place of `L2` like this:

```
FileName2 = Right(Range("L2"), 4)
```

---

Since you may be calling this macro from another sheet you should fully qualify the location of `L2` like this: (assuming the cell is on sheet1)

```
FileName2 =Right(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L2"), 4)
```

---

Per @Floris comment, you can shorthand `[L2]` for `Range("L2")`

```
FileName2 = Right([L2], 4)
```

Comment: I prefer to use `[L2]` - this is VBA shorthand for `Range("L2")`. And isn't it a lot less typing? `Filename2 = Right([L2], 4)`.